# failed to create java virtual machine error in springsource tool?

Tags: java, spring

I have downloaded springsource tool. But on install, it is giving me error "failed to create java virtual machine". Can anyone suggest me some solution?

This is my sts.ini

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502

-product
com.springsource.sts.ide

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5

-Xmn128m
-Xms256m

-Xmx768m

-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m

Comment: Is there any more text from the error you can post?

Comment: @kmb385 no there no error expect "failed to create java virtual machine error"

Comment: are you using the zip or the windows installer? do you have the jdk installed and your java home set?

Comment: give my answer a try, if you need help or problem resides let me know

Comment: @kmb385 i have already install jdk 6 and i am using zip file

Comment: @Akshay let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2168/discussion-between-kmb385-and-akshay)

Answer (score 8):

Find your sts.ini file usually in the root directory where you installed spring, try adding this as the first line in the file, make sure it points to YOUR JDK (You may need to change the path), also sometimes you need to put -vm and the path on different lines.

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe
```

My sts.ini

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: you tried -vm on one line and C:\.. on another? post your sts.ini file if you would

Comment: make sure the -vm argument is the first line in the file, and if you add that as the first line make sure you remove the other -vm from the sts.ini, you may want to make a copy before doing this.

Comment: I came across this issue few days back, I could not find sts.ini file but -vm argument needs to be added in configuration file for STS of type ; Configuration setting.

Answer (score 3):

Today I had this problem with spring source tool and the resolution specified here worked better: [Could not create the Java virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891366/could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

```
-Xmn128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m 
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

Reduced/changed max heap size to be same as MaxPermSize, and STS started without issues.
-Xmx768m ---> -Xmx384m

Make sure your heap sizes are less than your RAM.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may have a similar issue as myself, your path to javaw.exe may be different. My path turned out to be:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe

In the command line, run `where java` and use that path to javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

Combining these two lines worked for me also.
    -vm
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

Today I had this problem with spring source tool and the resolution specified here worked better:

Reduced/changed max heap size to be same as MaxPermSize, and STS started without issues

-XX:PermSize=128m,
Xmx768m ---> -Xmx384m