# Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, linux, jvm

facing some problem with java virtual machine initialization. when i am using root account i can properly work with java. but when i am a user account it returns following errors

```
user@host# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

It does not seems like a memory issue as the same command works with root account. Available memory (free -m) is more than 1200MB
Also i have tried increasing the JVM memory limits

Comment: Are you sure both are using the same java executable? Also, I think you can limit memory available to a specific user, if you do ulimit -a as the user, does it say a limit for max memory size?

Comment: two line related to memory goes like `max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 200000`

Comment: `virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 200000`

Comment: I **guess**, you need to give your Java application a proper security permission to change memory in user mode.

Comment: Or, check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319551/java-refuses-to-start-in-linux-under-low-privilege-users-works-fine-as-root

Comment: @UdaySawant I have commented a new one just now. Just look into it

Comment: @eee could you please guide me about increasing this virtual memory limit. i tried setting up `/etc/profiles` and `/etc/profiles.d/limits.sh` but it doesn't reflect the changes in user account ulimit -a

Comment: What did you add in those two files? Did you relogin as the user after changing them ? Does ulimit -a show identical output to before

Comment: @MattFreake its working now, I edited the file `/etc/bashrc` with same contents as in `/etc/profiles` and in `/etc/profiles.d/limits.sh` and did a re-login. Thanks for reply man...

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Just be careful. You will get this message if you try to enter a command that doesn't exist, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/java -v
```

Comment: Your comment made my day. Now if I were just smart enough to setup notifications of nice comments to my email from Stackoverflow. hahahaha

Comment: This solved my problem, too. The command is -version in openjdk-8, but --version (two dashes) in openjdk-11. They really need a better "unknown command" error message >_<

Comment: I installed openjdk-8 inside an ubuntu 16.04 distrobox container, because I needed the java appletviewer, which worked fine so far.

But I also saw the mentioned error message for 'java --version', which made me tear my hair out.

To be honest, this goes under the heading of RTFM - a simple 'java -<TAB><TAB>' (which shows up the command completion) or a 'man java' would have solved the issue, instead I thought, the java package wasn't installed correctly...

But IMHO it's some kind of sick to throw such an error message instead of showing the correct syntax for the command's options!

Answer (score 10):

Set the JVM memory:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M`

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue today, and for me the problem was that I had allocated too much memory:

`-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Once I reduced the PermGen space, everything worked fine:

`-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

I know that doesn't look like much of a difference, but my machine only has 4GB of RAM, and apparently that was the straw that broke the camel's back. The Java VM was failing immediately upon every action because it was failing to allocate the memory.

Answer (score 2):

The problem got resolved when I edited the file `/etc/bashrc` with same contents as in `/etc/profiles` and in `/etc/profiles.d/limits.sh` and did a re-login.

Comment: Try `java -version` first before doing what he suggested. Also it's the answer by the questioner and doesn't explain what exactly the steps doing...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the physical available memory is more then VM defined min/max memory.