Keycloak error - Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
I have to experiment with Keycloak version 12 or 18. But unfortunately, I should be able to download the Keycloak version only above 21 by using the link - https://www.keycloak.org/downloads-archive.html
My application allows me to create a realm over the web ui. Over that realm customer could configure their own authentication entry point, I mean their own login page for the app.
I have an issue on opening some offset URL, which generally opens up a page if the user is in - session, else over the login again that particular page opens up. But it is not happening over the configured customized realm that they call it as OIDC
In order to look out I supposed to reproduce the error in my local system. For utilizing the option create a realm, I must be configuring Keycloak first.
I have a problem running Keycloak over JDK8, that it is supports. If I run with Java 11 I gets this issue,
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/quarkus/bootstrap/runner/QuarkusEntryPoint has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

So, I myself turned to JDK8. However, I am facing the following issue,
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java. Base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I am running kc.bat from KeyCloak_Home\bin directory.
And this error comes from keycloak version 21.0.0 to the latest - 24.0.3
Please help me in solving this issue.
Over the discussion, I think, first of all,-

kc.bat needs <<mandatory_args>>

with kc.bat start-dev I've succeeded, also I've made considerations in JDK version

The question is tagged with MongoDB Realm but the correlation is not clear. Can you update the question to indicate how Realm ties in?

I am not using MongoDB here. Also, I am not sure that Keycloak uses MongoDB internally. I am not finding the right reason to tag this question under MongoDB. Can you please explain it to me clearly

The question is tagged Realm which is part of MongoDB Realm (hover over or click to see the tag). Tagging it with Realm would indicate the question has something to do with MongoDB Realm

Realm is applicable over here is as well. Maybe this should be conveyed to the Moderators. So, they can change the description for the Realm tag. Not my mistake

Hmm. That's not how tags work but I understand what you are saying. An existing tag should not be changed as it would then loose it's context on the Realm questions it was used on (which is all of them)- and Realm has been used thousands of times referring to Realm. Additionally Realm is (was) the proper name of an existing copyrighted product. The proper process is to use something specific like Keycloak-realm or omit the tag entirely. I have removed it from the question to avoid crossover as by your comments, it has nothing to do with Realm.

You get an exception telling you that your Java version is too old and you try to solve it by switching to an even older version?

By the way you can download old version of keycloak on their github releases page https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases

@DevAnandSadasivam have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891366/could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine

keycloak-24.0.3 works properly with Java 17. I ran kc.bat start-dev command.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run Keycloak locally on your local machine? In that case, you can use Docker to create it and pull the image like this: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.0. Maybe 24 also works, but I have not tested that. Then the whole Docker YAML will look something like this:
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/mariadb:11
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      MARIADB_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "9080:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.0
    environment:
      keycloak.url: http://keycloak:8888
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8888
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: "true"
      KC_DB: mariadb
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://mysql:3306/${KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME}?characterEncoding=UTF-8
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false
      HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KC_LOG: console
      KC_PROXY: none
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command:
      - "start-dev"
      - "--http-port=8888"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8888/health/ready" ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
volumes:
  mariadb-data:

On site note I did not create this yaml myself its from another post on here but I forgot the question
You can also remove phpmyadmin from this image we just had it for debugging cases
